# Can the Properties Shelf be re-merged in 2.8?

Tags: interface

In Blender 2.8 the Properties Shelf seems to have been split into four different shelves by default, called Item, Tool, Edit, and View.

Is there any way to merge these back together so that you can just hit N to access them? Currently N only opens the most recent shelf you've used, and you have to physically click open a different one if you want it.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so (but...). Maybe, consider 2.79 brings its habits, and few hours (minutes ?) working in 2.8 will break them.

Comment: It's not really a matter of habit. I already have the new habit. I just think it's much less efficient, especially with a large monitor. I could have all of the tabs I needed expanded on the old properties shelf, and I still didn't need to scroll to use it. Much quicker than having to click different shelves open, constantly going back and forth.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue, in fact. But ok, you choose the tab, and its ok. But surely, I understand what you are saying. Maybe you should ask to Blender developers?

Comment: I was planning on posting on DevTalk about it, but I wanted to make absolutely sure that the option didn't currently exist first.

Comment: Although it is a little bit annoying, but those element group by a proper tab now. Which should be more correct, I guess. And most of the time, when they are all in one tab, some elements will need to scroll down to reach it, especially in a small viewing area. And also considering add-on to utilize these tabs name, it will make those add-on more easier to choose a default tab rather create a new tab

Comment: Someone pointed out to me on devtalk that you can shift + left click on the individual elements to pin them in place, so that is at least something. That might actually be the answer for now.

Comment: Each panel is placed in a tab named after its `bl_category` property. In theory, you could remove all these and end up with one tab.

Answer (score 1):

The properties shelves can't be re-merged in Blender 2.8, but you can retain specific elements from each shelf by Shift + Left-Clicking on them and pinning them. The pinned elements will be retained through toggling the whole Properties Shelf with N.

[image]